# How to format the spgridview filter data?

Tags: filter, spgridview

I have a SPGridView where I am binding a calculation field. I am dynamically binding data to sp grid view in a web part.

The filter value is displaying like `String;#filterexp1`, `String;#filterexp3`, `String;#filterexp2` but I need it to display like `filterexp1`, `filterexp2`, `filterexp3`.

Is that possible to format the filter expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but it is kind of a hack.

**Step 1: Make your filter values pretty**

For this, you'll need to create a class inheriting from SPGridView and override the `GetCallbackResult` function:

```
public class SPFilterGridView : SPGridView
{
   protected override string GetCallbackResult()
   {
      string result = base.GetCallbackResult();

      // do something to alter the result
      // result = ...;

      return result;
   }
}
```

You'll need to debug to get it right but you should be able to clean up the list here.

**Step 2: Fix your FilterExpression**

After you make your filter values pretty, you'll notice that the filter won't work anymore. This will be due to your `FilterExpression` trying to filter on the new "pretty" values instead of the ugly `String;#filterexp1` values which are the actual values.

You probably want to override `OnPreRender` in your web part to dynamically fix your DataSource's FilterExpression:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreRender(e);

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridDS.FilterExpression))
   {
      string fieldName = _grid.FilterFieldName;
      // TODO: whatever logic to reformat FilterExpression (add String;# in there??)
      _gridDS.FilterExpression = string.Format(format, value, fieldName);
   }
}
```